# How to mock a method in a module in ruby?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, mocking

I have `number_module.rb` with content:

```
def power2(x)
  x * x
end
```

and test case `tc_number.rb`:

```
require_relative('number_module')
require "test/unit"
require 'mocha/test_unit'

class TestSimpleNumber < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_simple
    assert_equal(4, power2(2) ) # how to mock power2 to return 3?
  end

end
```

in order to practice mocking i want to mock power2 in the test case to return `3` instead of `powering by 2` how can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/), it looks like you can just use `expects(:method_name).returns(result)` :

```
def power2(x)
  x * x
end
require "test/unit"
require 'mocha/test_unit'

class TestSimpleNumber < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_simple
    expects(:power2).returns(3)
    assert_equal(4, power2(2) )
  end
end
```

The test fails as expected :

```
Loaded suite mocha
Started
F
=============================================================================================================================================================
Failure: test_simple(TestSimpleNumber)
mocha.rb:10:in `test_simple'
      7: class TestSimpleNumber < Test::Unit::TestCase
      8:   def test_simple
      9:     expects(:power2).returns(3)
  => 10:     assert_equal(4, power2(2) ) # how to mock power2 to return 3?
     11:   end
     12: end
<4> expected but was
<3>
```